# at least $3$ digit not goes to its exact position

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

> Total number of arrangements of the $5$ digit number $12345$ in which at least $3$ digits are not in their exact position is?

My attempt:

At least $3$ digits do not go to their exact position = exactly $3$ digits not in their exact position + exactly $4$ digits not in their exact position + exactly $5$ digits not in their exact position.

For all $5$ not in their position, the number of cases are $$5!\bigg(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}\bigg)$$

How do I solve it from here? Please help me.

Comment: The three cases are mutually exclusive, so just find for each one. For exactly 3, choose two, fix them and then the problem is equivalent to derangement of 3. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of digits not fixed can be $3,4,5$ and these are mutually exclusive.

For example, for all $5$ not in their place, the formula is given as you mentioned, using the inclusion exclusion principle. Let us call the number of such permutations as $R$. Get $R = 44$.

Now, fix any one digit in these : now, we have to displace four numbers so that none of them are in their positions : this would give $4!(1 - \frac 1{1!} + \frac 1{2!} ...)$. Call this quantity $S$, we get $5S$ for this block. Get $S = 9$.

Fix any two digits : this can be done in $10$ ways . Next switch the remaining $3$ around for no matches : you would get(can be counted by hand) only $2$ such arrangements. Add everything up.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly 4 digits not in position , first choose the one in position and then derange 4.

$$ = {5 \choose 1} 4! \left[ 1-\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!}+ \frac{1}{4!} \right] = 5×9 = 45 $$

For 3 not in position = $5 \choose 2$(number of derangement of 3 things) = $10 \times 2$

Answer is $44 + 45 + 20 = 109$

Comment: The number of derangements of three objects is $D_3 = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been commented, you can split into mutually exclusive cases, where exactly 5, 4, or 3 digits are not in their exact positions. However I find it much easier to enumerate the cases where exactly 5, 4, or 3 digits *are* in their exact positions, and subtract these from $5! = 120$ total permutations.

- Total number of permutations: $5! = 120$ permutations.
- Exactly 5 digits in exact position: $1$ permutation.
- Exactly 4 digits in exact position: not possible, if 4 digits are in exact position then the 5th one must also be, so $0$ permutations.
- Exactly 3 digits in exact position: from 5 digits you can choose 2 to swap, which makes $\binom{5}{2}! = 10$ permutations.

For there to be *at least 3* digits *not in* exact position, that means there must be 0, 1, or 2 digits *in* exact position; that is, less than 3 digits in exact position. So the answer is the total number of permutations, minus the total number of cases where 3, 4, or 5 digits is in exact position. This is $120 - 1 - 0 - 10$, or $109$ permutations.

You can also check it by brute force with a program, by constructing all 120 permutations, and then checking which ones have at least 3 digits not in exact position. The following code does this in Python, and confirms the answer is 109.

```
import itertools as it
digits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
answer = 0
for p in it.permutations(digits):
    notexact = [x!=y for x, y in zip(p, digits)]
    if sum(notexact) >= 3:  # at least 3 digits not in exact position
        answer += 1
print(answer)
>> 109
```

Out of 120 total permutations, $12345$ itself has 5 digits in exact position, and the following 10 permutations have 3 digits in exact position:
$$\left\{ 12354, 12435, 12543, 13245, 14325, 15342, 21345, 32145, 42315, 52341\right\}$$
The other 109 permutations have at most 2 digits in exact position / have at least 3 digits not in exact position.